# LLN of random nearest neighbor function

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, limits-and-convergence

There are two samples of iid random variates: $X=\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$ and $Y=\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n\}$. Further, $\forall i,j: X_i$ is independent of $Y_j$. The probability distributions $P,Q$ are unknown but have the same support and the a.e. continuously differentiable pdf's $p$ and $q$. $X_i \sim P$ and $Y_i \sim Q$. Let $\mathcal Q_i^k$ be the number of the $k$ nearest neighbors of $X_i$. Then, $N_i=|\mathcal Q_i^k \cap X|$ is the number of neighbors that are from $X$. I assume that the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is constant in the neighborhood. $k$ is assumed to be small enough w.r.t $n$ such that $\forall \ Y_{i,l} \in \mathcal Q_i^k$ (where $Y_{i,l}$ is the $l$th neighbor of $X_i$) it holds that
\begin{align*}
B_{i,l}=Ber(\theta_{i})= \begin{cases} 1 \quad Y_{i,l} \in X \\
                                       0 \quad \text{else}
                         \end{cases}
\end{align*}
with $\theta_i=\frac{p(X_i)}{p(X_i) + q(X_i)}$. Note that $N_{i,k}= \sum_{l=1}^kB_{i,l}$ and therefore $N_{i,k} \sim Bin_{k,\theta_i}$. Now I have a nearest neighbor random function
\begin{align*}
f_k(X_i):= \log\left(\frac{N_{i,k} + \varepsilon_1}{k - N_{i,k} + \varepsilon_2}\right) \quad \text{with} \quad \varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2 > 0
\end{align*}
It holds that $\lim_{n \to \infty} k= \infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac kn=0$. E.g. $k=k(n):=\sqrt(n)$ does the job. I have shown that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(X_i)=f(X_i):=\log\left(\frac{p(X_i)}{q(X_i)}\right)
\end{align*}
Due to the construction, $f_k(X_i), f_k(X_j)$ are not pairwise independent, but $f(X_i), f(X_j)$ are. Now I want to show that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_i^n f_k(X_i)=E[f(X)]
\end{align*}
Maybe you have noticed what kind of estimator this is. So $k$ is a function of $n$, but it is not growing during the summation. If $n=\infty$, then $k =\infty$ and thus $f_k(x)=f(x)$. And AFTER THAT I take the sum. That would be:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_i^n f_k(X_i)=  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_i^n \lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(X_i) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_i^n f(X_i) = E[f(X)]
\end{align*}
Is that correct? For me, it feels wrong and I would like to be able to swap $\lim_{k \to \infty}$ with the sum and write:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i}^nf_k(X_i)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i}^{n}\lim_{k \to \infty}f_k(X_i).
\end{align*}
However, as $f_k(X_i)$ is neither monotone increasing nor decreasing, I can not apply monotone convergence. Further, I have not found an integrable (w.r.t 'mass density' $\frac1n$) function $g(X_i)$ with $g(X_i)\geq |f_k(X_i)|$, as $f_k(X_i)\approx\log(k)$ in the worst case (that is $N_{i,k}=k$).

Comment: instead of down voting that question, it would be nice to give an answer.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. But your question is incomprhensible. For instance, what are the functions $f_k$?

Comment: you might want to explain the meaning of the equation $\lim_{n \to \infty} k= \infty$ --- I don't see that you have specified how $k$ depends on $n$; and LLN = ... ?

Comment: I wrote now the definition of $f_k$ and gave an example how $k$ depends on $n$.

Comment: What are *the $k$ nearest neighbors of $X_i$?*